# Android: Update menu toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin

In a fragment, I want to load a modified toolbar menu when I click on a line in the adapter. As soon as I unmark the line, the normal menu should appear again. How do I do it?
The problem in my experiment is that "invalidateOptionsMenu" is completely unknown and I cannot update the menu using the context ("c"). When turning the cell phone it works, but this is not a practical solution. How can I unmark this so that the normal menu is displayed again?

```
class BoardFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {

        if(MEINMENUE.equals("A")){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
            true
        }else if(MEINMENUE.equals("B")){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu_file_selected, menu)
            true
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }    
    
    public class MyAdapter constructor(
        val c: Context, var title: Array<String> ) : ArrayAdapter<String>(c, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, title) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            
            val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater =  c.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val row: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
            
            row.setOnLongClickListener { view ->

                MEINMENUE ="B"
                //requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()

                true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);            
        return root
    }       
    
    companion object {
        private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"
        var MEINMENUE : String = "A"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not "seeing" the `invalidateOptionsMenu` or `requireActivity` is that in Kotlin the inner classes needs to be explicitly declared. Your `MyAdapter` is now static class so it cannot call any functions from `BoardFragment`. You can declare adapter class as inner class, then you can call `requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`:

```
public inner class MyAdapter // and so on...
```

Better way could be to pass some sort of listener to `MyAdapter` for View's long click.